# Java - add text to button's text arraylist

Tags: java, button, arraylist, javafx

I am assigning several buttons to a gridpane. Each button has a number as its text. I created an arrayList numbers and add numbers to it. I use collections to shuffle the numbers **(I want to have a random number in each button everytime I run the program)**. Then I add a number to each button text using this arrayList.

I want each button to have a different number. However, right now each button in 1 column have the same number.

Any suggestions on how to fix this issue will be greatly appreciated (random assignment of the text of button).

This is my code:

```
Button[][] b= new Button[2][2];
List<Integer> n = new ArrayList<>();

    for(int i=0; i <2; i++){
        for(int j=0; j <2; j++){
            b[i][j] = new Button(String.valueOf(n.get(i)));
            pane.add(button[i][j], i, j);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

With `numbers.get(i)` you are only accessing the first 4 numbers in your `ArrayList`, since `i` iterates from `0` to `3`.

Change

```
b[i][j] = new Button(String.valueOf(numbers.get(i)));
```

to

```
b[i][j] = new Button(String.valueOf(n.get(i*4+j)));
```

Edit :

Note that you should use the `n` `ArrayList`, Not `numbers` (which I have no idea what it contains).

Comment: It works I had an error when I typed it in my code. Thank you